# How to add directory and sub directories in installer package

Tags: nsis

I have many files and folders to be added to my installation package. I tried command

> File /nonfatal /a /r "C:\Users\test\hdp*"

and

> File /nonfatal /a /r "C:\Users\test\hdp\"

but it didn't create the output file(.exe). I also tried with zip file (means created zip file of hdp folder) and add it into package but the same issue i am facing with zip file also.
hdp folder size is 250MB only.

In documentation also no option is mentioned to add folder. Can someone suggest how to add these folder and subfolders to the package?

Answer (score 1):

You should start with Example1.nsi and understand all of its instructions before trying to write a real installer.

```
OutFile "myinstaller.exe" ; Name of generated installer .exe
InstallDir "$Desktop\MyApp" ; Change this

Page Directory
Page InstFiles

Section
SetOutPath $InstDir
File /r "c:\users\test\myfilestoinstall\*.*" ; Change this
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks Anders,  I am using a similar way. I just added commands only in the post.